# How to create a button with changing caption in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I'm trying to create a button that will change its caption to included when pressed and excluded if not pressed. I have tried to do that, but received an error.

Please, see my screenshot.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: You may wanna post your code here

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no value property for button so instead check for caption
2. move the code inside sheet1 module (assuming button2 is inside sheet1) to access the button by parent scope

   Sub button2_click()
      If button2.caption = "include" then
        button2.caption = "exclude"
      Else
        button2.caption = "include"
      End if
    End sub